# javascript callback on function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return

I'm trying run a function in return of another function:

```js
var my_func = function(func){
 if(typeof func=="function") return func;
}
my_func(function(){
 alert('hello world!');
});
```

but it does not work!

Comment: **Typo and missing function invocation** `reutn func` ==> `return func();`

Comment: @Tushar correct answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the function

```js
var my_func = function (func) {
    if (typeof func == "function") return func();
    //                                        ^^ call function
}
my_func(function () {
    alert('hello world!');
});
```

Comment: @NinaScholz both parenthesis together, i don't understand

Comment: @Nabi, yes it works sometimes, because you are returning sometimes a function and sometimes not. if you everytime return a function, then the parenthesis makes sense at last.